# Why jQuery cycle plugin doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write a function to append some HTML code to page like below:

```
function addGiftList(className, imgURL, Kind) {
    var $li = $('<li class="' + className + '">');
    var $img = $("<img>", { src: imgURL })
    var $br = $("<br/>");
    var $input = $('<input >', { type: 'radio', name: 'gift', kind: Kind });
    var $label = $("<label>").text("Test");

    $li.append($img);
    $li.append($br);
    $li.append($input);         
    $li.append($label);
    return $li;         
}
```

All this will append to a div with className `cycle-slideshow` then I call `$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle();`, but nothing happens. Does anyone know why?
Can I create HTML elements with javascript then call jQuery cycle plugin?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Nothing show on console.THanks

Comment: please, show your `cycle` method

Comment: Make sure you are loading plugin's js before you initialize the component

Comment: Thanks for reply. i download cycle js file from its website.

Comment: I directly call .cycle() on console. so i am sure the component is initialise.

Comment: Your final HTML has a structure as `div.cycle-slideshow > ul > li` or `div.cycle-slideshow > li` ?

Comment: Yes, you can create `DOM` either by writing markup or by using `Javascript`  to build DOM. When you use `Javascript` to build/change DOM, make sure the change is done before using those parts of `DOM Tree`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button>append</button>
<div class="myslider composite-example" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="2000">
  <div>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" width=100%>
    <div class="cycle-overlay">first image</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg" width=100%>
    <div class="cycle-overlay">second image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
 // first call cycle
    $('.myslider').length > 0 && $('.myslider').cycle();

    function addGiftList(className, imgURL, Kind) {
        var $div = $('<div class="' + className + '">');
        var $img = $("<img>", {
                src: imgURL
            })
        var $input = $('<input >', {
            type: 'radio',
            name: 'gift',
            kind: Kind
        });
        var $label = $("<label>").text("Test");
        $div.append($img);
        $div.append($input);
        $div.append($label);

        // dynamically adding slider: this is a plugin method see documentation
        $('.myslider').cycle('add', $div);

        return;
    }

    // dynamic add button for example
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        // add function for example
        addGiftList('myclass cycle-slide', 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=image%20added&w=200&h=150&txttrack=0');
    })
```

Please see this link of my codepen. I have solved your problem.
http://codepen.io/prashen/pen/PNPbRR

Comment: @aBloomer please check this solution.